# Calling convention of overloaded operator within structure?

Tags: c++, g++

I was revisiting the concepts of structures in C++ before the lectures and written the following:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct isOdd{
  bool operator()(int x){
    return x%2;
  }
};

int main(){
 vector<int> v {3,4,2,1,65,2,4,65,2,9,8,5,7};

 int count = count_if(begin(v), end(v), isOdd());

 cout << "size of vector: " <<v.size() << endl;
 cout << "count of odds: " <<count << endl;
 return 0;
}
```

Then I realize that in calling function of structure isOdd, I have used the syntax: isOdd() but I have only overridden the () operator. So how the calling convention isOdd() is working because the calling a function of structure is like:
structure::function-name();
or structure-object.functions-name();

Can somebody elaborate the doubt?

Thanks.

Comment: `isOdd()` call the default constructor of `isOdd`, to call your operator, you would have to use `isOdd()(42)`, and `std::count_if` calls your `opearator ()` from the predicate/class `isOdd` you give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Then I realize that in calling function of structure isOdd, I have
>   used the syntax: isOdd() but I have only overridden the () operator.

No, You called the implicit *compiler generated* default constructor, thereby creating a temporary object of `isOdd`.

For example: If you wanted to test it on a single number without creating a named `isOdd` object, you could:

```
bool is_odd = isOdd()(4);
                 //^^ Creates a temporary object
```

---

*Optimizing Compilers will elide the creation of the temporary object since it neither has observable side effects nor a state.*

Comment: But the calling convention is object.<member-function>/<data-member>(). Like isOdd().function-name();

Comment: @AmarjeetSharma, *"But the calling convention is object.<member-function>/<data-member>(). Like isOdd().function-name();"* - Yes true. But, `operators` have a short-hand notation where you skip the name `operator` and simply use the symbol... The "function-name()" notation you are looking for will be [**`isOdd().operator() (4);`**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/817573d3e0c3346e),

Comment: Ok. Like if instead of overloaded operator () there is a function checkOdd(int x) then the calling would be : isOdd().checkOdd(4). but the it is operator ie checkOdd ===> operator() thus the calling would be: isOdd().operator() after that the argument within bracket as pointed by you. so it would be isOdd().operator() (4) which by virtue of short hand notation we can skip .operator() and directly write the argument with braces. But this is special case only for operators. Please confirm.

Comment: @AmarjeetSharma, you simply pass the address of the non member function like: `std::count_if(std::begin(v), std::end(v), isOdd);` or `std::count_if(std::begin(v), std::end(v), &isOdd);`. The first case [works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a13ebd208824bad8) because using the name of a non-member functions or a static member functions will yield its address

Comment: I verified the same : isOdd().operator() (4); it worked as described.

Comment: `std::count_if(std::begin(v), std::end(v), isOdd); or std::count_if(std::begin(v), std::end(v), &isOdd);` both statements are not working only the statement : `std::count_if(std::begin(v), std::end(v), isOdd());` is working.

Comment: @AmarjeetSharma, forget my previous comment (I thought you were talking about ***non-member functions*** before you edited your comment.. It only applies to ***non-member functions*** and ***static member functions***.... As to the confirmation you seek for in your [previous comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43343061/calling-convention-of-overloaded-operator-within-structure/43343185?noredirect=1#comment73752081_43343185) *("...But this is special case only for operators. Please confirm."* - Yes. I confirm. That's correct

Comment: Thanks @WhiZTiM now I can take my first lecture peacefully.